# Vuejs error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im not sure if this is a bug in Vuejs or something I am doing wrong.

I am trying to return counts for each equipment type. For example:

Item 1, Hammer, 100

Item 2, Hammer, 200

Item 3, Screwdriver, 100

Totals: Hammer = 300, Screwdriver = 100

I am using 'watch' to keep the count update to date when an item's quantity is changed. This works fine for the first couple of updates but then I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null and the totals disappear. Any ideas?

```
watch: {
    'equipment': function(val) {

        for (var i in this.equipmentTypes) {
            var count = 0;
            var id = this.equipmentTypes[i].id;
            var name = this.equipmentTypes[i].name;
            this.equipment.filter(function(item){       
                if(item.equipment_type_id == id){
                    count += parseFloat(item.quantity);
                }
            });
            this.equipmentCounts.$set(id,{name: name,value: count});
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Not sure why but this is the data contained in equipmentsCount:
[ null, { "name": "Hammer", "value": 12 }, { "name": "Screwdriver", "value": 12 }, { "name": "Nail", "value": 0 }, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ]
I suspect the null values have something to do with the issue I just dont know where they are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I should have been using push instead:

```
this.equipmentCounts.push({name: name, value: count});
```